# R sum on rows based on day

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, cumsum

I have a dataframe containing sells by day, but as there are many values for one day, so i'd like to rebuilt my dataframe to have just one value per day which is the sum of all the sells of this day.

what i have:

[image: what i have]

what i'd like to have:

[image: enter what i'd like to have here]

(the values are not well calculated but it's for the example)

I tried agregate and functions like this but it dosn't work and I dont know how to do this...

Thanks for help

Comment: Yeah it's a duplicate but it's very easy with data.table :
`setDT(df)[, tot_by_day = sum(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT), by = DATE_ID]`

Comment: setDT(df)[, tot_by_day = sum(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT), by = DATE_ID]
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), , tot_by_day = sum(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT),  : 
  unused argument (tot_by_day = sum(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT))

Comment: Your command should work but I dont understand why I have this error

Comment: It's probably due to the name of your columns. Check if the syntax is correct + don't forget to install the package and load if it's not the case by writing : `install.packages("data.table")` then `require(data.table)`

Comment: Now i have this, I changed types and I tested your command and I get this
setDT(df)[, sum(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT), by=DATE_ID]
   DATE_ID V1
1:    <NA> NA

And now my dates are all NA in my df

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate should work

```
aggregate(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT,by=list(DATE_ID),FUN=sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have the following error (I saw this lone like a million times)

"Error in Summary.factor(c(37299L, 44973L, 34393L, 29184L, 39963L, 30029L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors"

Comment: TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT needs to be numeric. 

`as.numeric(as.character(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT))`

Comment: I've already done it but this doesn't change anything

Comment: `TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT <- as.numeric(as.character(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT))` to be more specific, did you do that?

Comment: It actually worked! Thanks Mr.Bugle :)

Comment: Awesome, gotta remember to actually update the variable :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
df <- data.frame(DATE_ID = 1, TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT = 1)
aggregate(TOT_OP_MAIN_PAID_MNT ~ DATE_ID, df, sum)
```